How to parallelize a simple function using MPI4PY?
Suppose I have the following simple function:
def f(x):
  return x*x

How do I parallelize this function using the mpi4py library?
Instead of x being a float, I would like to supply an array and parallelize the computation such that each process receives a chunk of the array and performs the computation.
My attempt,
def parallel_f(input_array):
if rank == 0:
    print("Running a parallelized version of f. \n")
    xdata = input_array
    data_size = xdata.shape[0]
    chunk_size = data_size // size
    ydata = np.zeros((data_size), dtype = float)
else:
    xdata = None
    data_size = None
    chunk_size = None
    ydata = None

xdata = comm.bcast(xdata, root = 0)
data_size = comm.bcast(data_size, root = 0)
chunk_size = comm.bcast(chunk_size, root = 0)
local_data = np.zeros_like(xdata, dtype = float)
lb = int(rank * chunk_size)
ub = int((rank + 1) * chunk_size)
comm.Barrier()
for i in range(lb, ub):
    x = xdata[i]
    y = f(x)
    local_data[i] = y

comm.Barrier()
comm.Reduce(local_data, ydata, op = MPI.SUM, root = 0)
if rank == 0:
    for i in range(size * chunk_size, data_size):
        x = xdata[i]
        ydata[i] = f(x)
    print("The result of operation is: ")
    for i in range(data_size):
        print(str(ydata[i]))
return

However, for some reason, this does not seem to work on a cluster computer. I am not receiving any error message but a sequential computation on my laptop finishes before the parallelized computation finishes on the cluster.
Any feedback will be appreciated.
I am running this python script on the cluster using sbatch.
